# Escaping characters in sed

Tags: sed, escaping

I am trying to replace the value of a couple of php database array variables with sed, but it is not working as expected

Here is an example:

```
echo \$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL' | sed "s|^$DB['TYPE']=.*$|$DB['TYPE']='POSTGRESQL'|g"
```

Im trying to replace `$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL'   with   $DB['TYPE']='POSTGRESQL'`

I escaped it this way but does not work, I keep getting `$DB[TYPE]=MYSQL`

```
echo \$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL' | sed "s|^\$DB[\'TYPE\']=.*$|\$DB[\'TYPE\']=\'POSTGRESQL\'|g"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to replace `$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL'   with   $DB['TYPE']='POSTGRESQL'`

You can use:

```
sed "s|\(\$DB\['TYPE'\]=\)'MYSQL'|\1'POSTGRESQL'|g" file
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is still giving me $DB['TYPE']='MYSQL' as output in bash

Comment: Don't forget that `[...]` is regex bracket expression. Need to escape to match literal brackets.

Comment: The problem seem to be with the brackets, I tried to escape the brackets [] but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce duplication as much as possible:

```
$ echo "\$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL'" |
  sed  "s|^\(\$DB\['TYPE'\]='\)[^']*|\1POSTGRES|"
$DB['TYPE']='POSTGRES'
```

You use line anchors so the `g` modifier is useless -- the pattern can match at most once per line.

You need double quotes on the `echo` line. Without them, you get the shell seeing the single quotes as quote characters, not literal characters:

```
$ echo \$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL' 
$DB[TYPE]=MYSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

In you example sed doen"t find the exact phrase. Why don't you just exchange the word you want to exchange like

```
echo \$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL' | sed "s|MYSQL|POSTGRESQL|g"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this

```
echo "\$DB['TYPE']='MYSQL'" | sed "s|^\$DB\['TYPE'\]=.*$|\$DB\['TYPE'\]='POSTGRESQL'|"
```

It works as expected. Thanks guys.